# Java 3d Game Mouse Camera/Player control

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, game-physics

In my Game i want to implement Mouse Controls that control Camera and Player movment.

What i want to have is that when the Mouse moves to the bottom left corner of the window for example, the players Rotation goes towards this Vector. 
Also i want the Camera to be shifted in the opposite 2d Vector so it appears that the player, when the cursor is in the bottom left moves into the top right corner.

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I16j.png)

And the more the cursor is moved away from the screens middle, the more the player should rotate.
The Camera should also be rotated around the player in order to make it appear that the playermodel is rotated towards the vector it rotates itself in.

This is the function that calculates the camera position:

```
private void calculateCameraPosition(float horizDistance, float verticDistance)
{

    float theta = player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer;
    float offsetX = (float)((horizDistance ) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)) );
    float offsetZ = (float)(horizDistance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)));

    position.y = player.getPosition().y + verticDistance + 8;
    position.x = (player.getPosition().x - offsetX);
    position.z = player.getPosition().z - offsetZ ;
    this.yaw = 180 - (player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer);        
}
```

And i get my Inputs from GFLW, a little bit modified as the Mouse positions, which i subtract from the width/2 and divide into smaller numbers.

```
angleChange_x = (int) (-(inputHandler.Mouse_x - (Width/2)) /20);

angleChange_y = (int) (-(inputHandler.Mouse_y - (Height/2)) /20 );
```

Comment: What is not working with your current camera position calculation?

Comment: Also, I can't really see a question anywhere.